# How to access environment variables client-side (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, dotenv

I have declared some environment variables on my server using `dotenv`, and I want to be able to access one of them on my client-side code

I have my .env file set up like so:

```
NODE_ENV='development'
DEF_USER='admin'
```

then I have my `config.js` file where I load the variables from my env file:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');

dotenv.config({
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, `../environments/${process.env.NODE_ENV.trim()}.env`)
});

module.exports = {
    NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    DEF_USER: process.env.DEF_USER || 'admin'
};
```

How can I acces my `DEF_USER` variable on my client's code? I can access `NODE_ENV` with `process.env.NODE_ENV`, but no such luck with `DEF_USER`.

I should mention that my server and my client code is in separate directories.
Also, I didn't used `create-react-app`.

I also tried by installing `webpack` in my client but it trows me a lot of errors.

Comment: If you're using Express you can use a template engine.

Comment: If your server code and client code are in separate directories (as they must be for Node.js and React.js projects), they are bundled and deployed entirely separately. If you need the environment variable to be available in both places, I would recommend opening up an API endpoint to retrieve the value from the server on the client side or copy the value to a new .env file in the React project directory.

Comment: @JacobK you mean the root directory of the project?

Comment: Yes, the env files should be at the root directory of each project. You can alternatively open up the API endpoint to serve the relevant value to the front end, or you could even place the variables in a shared location and pull from it during the back- and front-end code build pipelines. But if the shared variable is something that is static such as a client ID or API key that rarely changes, the easiest solution is likely to copy it in both locations.

Comment: Also, you're able to see the `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable, not because you are reading it from your file, but rather because it is a default environment variable that is available by default (and cannot be overwritten) in a React app

Answer (score 0):

"You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name"

This is from React documentation, hope it helps. Link: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).